# Django Decode Json error

Tags: json, django

I have this json data that I post to Djangp

```
[[LAT2:1.3178775, LON1:103.7608174, LON2:103.7733836, LAT1:1.3104325, YPIXELS:378, XPIXELS:400, MINZ:40, XKNOTS:26, YKNOTS:24, MAXZ:80], [node:51, z:63.462589, y:1.312762, x:103.766148]]
```

Getting error: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

My codes:

```
jsonStr = request.body.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string isn't valid json. key:value pairs need to be encompassed in curly brackets, and keys must be quoted. For example: `{"key" : "value"}`

At minimum you're going to have to transform your string into this format:

`[{"LAT2":1.3178775, "LON1":103.7608174, "LON2":103.7733836, "LAT1":1.3104325, "YPIXELS":378, "XPIXELS":400, "MINZ":40, "XKNOTS":26, "YKNOTS":24, "MAXZ":80}, {"node":51, "z":63.462589, "y":1.312762, "x":103.766148}]'`

Here's a way to do it without regular expressions, if you know the keys in the string will be consistent:

```
 # Bracket the {key : value} structures:
 input = '[' + input[1:-1].replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}') + ']'

 # Wrap the keys in double quotes:
 keys = ('LAT2', 'LON1', 'LON2', 'LAT1', 'YPIXELS', 'XPIXELS', 
         'XKNOTS', 'YKNOTS', 'MINZ', 'MAXZ', 'node', 'z', 'y', 'x')

 for key in keys:
      input = input.replace(key, '"' + key + '"')
```